# How can I integrate with a Windows application which lacks a plug-in architecture?

Tags: windows, winapi

I need to make minor modifications to a legacy Win32 application, but have no access to the original developer or source code.  The application was not designed to be extended by third parties.  What are my options for doing this?

The changes required are not extensive: I need to launch an external application when a specific text label is clicked.

Is it possible to access and modify the controls in the target application from an outside application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for can be accomplished by either using a SetWindowsHookEx() hook, or subclassing the label directly, to detect when the label is clicked. Your hook/subclass can then launch the external process.

Comment: I won't necessarily say deep. A simple message hook might suffice.

Comment: Unsupported territory is probably fine since this application won't be changing.  Can you direct me to code samples for either approach?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to react when a text is clicked, you could try to use the [Microsoft UI Automation technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation), and in this case, [UI Automation Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-events-overview).

Note that depending on how the application is written, it may or may not work.

You can try the cool [Inspect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) and [Accessible Event Watcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd317979.aspx) tools at least to check if its seems feasible.